# Qt slot connection not working under child Dialog

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a text editor like program which is a `QMainWindow` inherited class. There, when I click **Find**, the connection,

```
connect(actionFind,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(actionFindTriggered()));
```

Activates. And the defination of that function is

```
void    MainWindow::actionFindTriggered() {
    new Find(this);
}
```

My `Find` class is

```
class Find : public QDialog, public Ui::Dialog
{
public:
    Find(QWidget *parent=0);

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;

public slots:
    void    buttonFindTriggered();
};
```

And the definition is

```
Find::Find(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    ui = new Ui::Dialog;
    ui->setupUi(this);
    show();
    this->

    connect(ui->buttonClose, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));
    connect(ui->buttonFind, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(buttonFindTrigddgered()));
}

void    Find::buttonFindTriggered() {
    qDebug() << "FIND ACTIVATED";
}
```

### What is the problem

When I clicked *find* from the main window, find window works successfully but could not make the **connection**. And I get the following msg on console,

```
Object::connect: No such slot QDialog::buttonFindTriggered() // Edited
Object::connect:  (sender name:   'buttonFind')
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'Dialog')
```

**Edited** due to a typo...!

Comment: Time to take a break ;) "buttonFindTrigddgered"

Comment: when in doubt - copy-paste variables. I do it every day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the Q_OBJECT macro.

Also - consider using this notation for getting slot auto-connection (setupUI will automatically connect these slot for you).

```
void on_buttonFind_clicked();
void on_buttonClose_clicked();
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, it can't find the slot:

```
buttonFindTrigddgered()
```

because it should be:

```
buttonFindTriggered()
```